# AutoHotkey for Ubuntu

Tags: wine, shortcuts

I need AutoHotkey to run certain commands.

I need it to press Space repeatedly every 200 milliseconds.
I also need it to use it for a couple of If/else commands and I'm not sure how AutoKey for Linux can do that. Maybe I'm ignorant for not doing my research, but I need a fast response.

Also, Wine doesn't work...

Comment: Welcome to SE.  I strongly recommend that you start off with some type of `Googgle` search to begin with.  This will help you to have some information for providing us with what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck.  We will be glad to assist.  But be kind.  Don't put all the work on us.  Try typing [THIS](https://www.google.com/#q=ubuntu+autokey+tutorial) into Google.  There are inks in that search that will bring up a tutorial for `auto typing`.  Also look at the right column.  It'll also give suggestions of solutions others have used.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate typing with the `xdotool`.

Install it using the command `sudo apt-get install xdotool` first.

Then you can make it emulate a single keystrokes like this:

```
xdotool key A
xdotool key space
xdotool key alt+F2
xdotool key X space plus space Y space equal space Z
```

Or you can tell it to emulate typing whole strings instead of single keys:

```
xdotool type 'I am typing words...'
xdotool type 'Never going to type with my fingers any more!'
```

Both on multiple keystrokes as well as on typing strings, you can specify a `--delay` option to control the delay between two keystrokes in milliseconds. The default is 12ms:

```
xdotool key --delay 500 X space plus space Y space equal space Z
xdotool type --delay 200 'I am typing words...'
```

Comment: That helps, but I want to be able when I HOLD SPACE for it to be actually pressed every 200 miliseconds. Can you help me here?

Comment: Don't think that's possible with plain shell scripting. Would it be okay to start the typing with a keyboard shortcut and to stop it again with another one or the same?